# Is there some program that can copy sparse file (/var/log/lastlog) over ssh as fast as cp (on local pc)?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sshfs, sparse-files

I'm backing ip my server via `rsync` over `ssh` but `/var/log/lastlog` file is 1.2G (it takes only 24K on the hdd).
On a local machine `cp` can copy it for no time (a few ms) but `rsync` requires reading the whole file which takes hours. I also tried to mount server's `/var/log` with `sshfs` to my local pc but my local pc detects the file as 1.2T (so `sshfs` doesn't appear to detect sparse files).
Is there some program that detects sparse files over ssh and can copy them the same way `cp` (without reading the empty blocks from the file) does?

EDIT: `rsync`'s `-S/--sparse` option still wants to read the whole source file (with all the empty bytes) which takes hours for 1.2T file. After `rsync` reads the whole file it creates small destination file (proper sparse file) but the problem is that it reads the source file with all the empty bytes (without skipping them). `cp` copies the file in a few ms while `rsync` takes hours. You can try it (on Linux) by creating 20G sparse file with `truncate -s 20G sparse_file1` and copy it with `rsync -S sparse_file1 sparse_file2` (takes long time) and then try to copy it with `cp sparse_file1 sparse_file3` (takes a few ms).

Comment: Have you tried `rsync`’s `-S` option?

Comment: Edited the answer adding some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, you are doing it as fine as it gets with `rsync -S`.

The reason `cp` is way faster is because it didn't really copy it. This can have many reasons, the first two that I can think of are:

- The system decided that the filesystem doesn't immediately need to sync and the copying will happen later in the background (or immediately when you run `sync`). See `man sync` for more info.
- You have a filesystem with cow/dedup-like features. The effect would be that `cp` created what I would call "a hard link in disguise". In this case the copy will never be made physically, the data in the file just gets a extra name (like a real hard link). But (in contrast to real hard links) when the source and destination file receive different changes in the future these changes will be saved physically at different places and the filesystem will bind the changes to the correct file. Checkout any docs about copy-on-write and data deduplication (e.g. the wikipedia pages) for more info.

Comment: I've done some testing in the past month and both of your points appear to be wrong in the current case.
I've copied the `lastlog` file to 2 USB flash drives (exFAT and ext4) from ext4 hdd and it copied for less than a second. Running sync took about a second.
Then I've did `hedump` on the original file and the file copied to the USB drive (plugged the USB drive to another PC to avoid Linux and filesystem messing with me) and they appear to be the same (couldn't wait for the whole 1.2T to compare).
The deal is that `cp` uses `SEEK_HOLE` skipping the 0s in the file while `rsync` does not.